# Make Jackson mapper serialize LocalDateTime JSON as Timestamp JSON

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson, timestamp, timezone

Due to my application timezone, **Jackson Object Mapper** is always increasing 3 hours (my timezone) to Timestamps I retrieve. I can not change the spring timezone because it would affect other parts of my application.

I have a field *timestamp* in my object that should have the following format:

```
2020-06-21T20:48:16.345+0000
```

In my database, timestamps are stored with an *applied timezone*, so the *+0000* part will always be *+0000*

However, the closest I could get with LocalDateTime is

```
2020-06-21T20:48:16.345
```

Is there any workaround or possible way to make Jackson Object Mapper retrieve a LocalDateTime the same way as a Timestamp?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parse your date-time string into `OffsetDateTime` using the pattern, `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ`.

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Given date-time string
        String strDate = "2020-06-21T20:48:16.345+0000";

        // Define formatter
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");

        // Get OffsetDateTime by applying the formatter
        OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse(strDate, formatter);
        System.out.println(odt);

        // If you want to get back the original date-time string
        strDate = odt.format(formatter);
        System.out.println(strDate);

        // If you want to get LocalDateTime
        LocalDateTime ldt = odt.toLocalDateTime();
        System.out.println(ldt);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2020-06-21T20:48:16.345Z
2020-06-21T20:48:16.345+0000
2020-06-21T20:48:16.345
```

**Note:** It almost certainly makes no sense to convert from `OffsetDateTime` to `LocalDateTime`. That conversion throws away valuable information, the offset, without adding any value.

Comment: Also, it helped a lot doing something like the following: `OffsetDateTime.ofInstant(timestamp.toInstant(), ZoneId.of("UTC"));`
I appreciate very much your answer! It was of good use!